# CakePHP - validation returning false

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

`validates()` getting failed, but the `validationErrors` is empty in CakePHP 2.x, even I have user `unlockedActions` for this method but still getting this error, while inserting its working fine. Only edit is not working.

This my controller code:

```
if (!empty($this->data['UserProfileName']['new']['new_profile_id'])){           
    // $this->data['UserProfileName']['old_profile_id'] = $this->data['UserProfileName']['profile_id'];
    $new_data['UserProfileName']['profile_id'] = $this->data['UserProfileName']['new']['new_profile_id'];
    $new_data['UserProfileName']['user_profile_id']=$userProfileId;
    $this->UserProfileName->create();   
    $this->UserProfileName->set($new_data); 
}       
$this->UserProfileContact->set($this->data);
if ($this->UserProfileName->validates() && $this->UserProfileContact->validates()) {
} else {
    $errors = $this->UserProfileName->validationErrors;
    $errors = $this->UserProfileContact->validationErrors;  
    pr($this->UserProfile->validationErrors);
    pr($errors);
}
```

The form input $this->data is:

```
 Array
(
    [UserProfile] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [expiry_date] => 2017-06-30
            [is_remarriage] => 0
            [is_featured] => 1
            [featured_date] => 2015-06-30
            [featured_expity_date] => 2015-07-15
            [language_id] => 1
            [name] => Profile1
            [gender_id] => 1
            [date_of_birth] => 1988-06-30
            [time_of_birth] => Array
                (
                    [hour] => 05
                    [min] => 11
                    [meridian] => pm
                )

            [place_of_birth] => Trichy
            [religion_id] => 1
            [caste_id] => 3
            [sub_caste_id] => 2
            [community_id] => 3
            [gothram_id] => 3
            [star_id] => 5
            [rasi_id] => 5
            [food_habbit_id] => 2
            [height] => 145
            [height_type_id] => 1
            [weight] => 50
            [complexion_id] => 2
            [blood_group_id] => 7
            [disability_id] => 
            [other_disability] => 
            [talents] => Singing
            [hobbies] => Handicrafts
            [languages_konwn] => Tamil, English,Hindi
            [qualification_id] => 1
            [other_qualification] => 
            [employment_type_id] => 5
            [job_details] => 
            [income] => 
            [income_type_id] => 1
            [parents_alive_type_id] => 2
            [father_name] => Fname
            [father_job] => Business
            [mother_name] => Mname
            [mother_job] => house wife
            [mother_caste_id] => 3
            [brothers_elder] => 2
            [brothers_younger] => 
            [brothers_married] => 1
            [sisters_elder] => 
            [sisters_younger] => 
            [sisters_married] => 
            [family_status_id] => 2
            [marital_status_id] => 
            [date_of_marriage] => 
            [date_of_divorce] => 
            [lived_together_duration] => 
            [cilidrean_details] => 
            [other_info] => 
            [is_show_photo] => 1
        )

    [UserProfileName] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [profile_id] => Profile1001
                )

            [new] => Array
                (
                    [new_profile_id] => 
                )

        )

    [PropertyType] => Array
        (
            [PropertyType] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )

    [UserProfileExpectation] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qualification_id] => 2
            [job_requirement_type_id] => 1
            [preferred_place_of_job] => With in Tamil nadu
            [min_income] => 900000/ann
            [caste_id] => 3
            [sub_caste_id] => 1
            [community_id] => 1
            [food_habbit_id] => 2
            [marital_status_id] => 1
            [is_horoscope_matching_required] => 1
            [is_accept_disablity] => 0
            [other_expectation] => 
        )

    [UserProfileHoroscopeDetail] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [balance_dasa_name] => sun
            [balance_dasa_years] => 12
            [balance_dasa_months] => 9
            [balance_dasa_days] => 25
            [rasi_1] => sss
            [rasi_2] => hggf
            [rasi_3] => ffgd
            [rasi_4] => 
            [rasi_12] => 
            [rasi_5] => 
            [rasi_11] => 
            [rasi_6] => dfgd
            [rasi_10] => 
            [rasi_9] => fgdfd
ghg
fgf
            [rasi_8] => 
            [rasi_7] => 
            [amsam_1] => 
            [amsam_2] => fg
            [amsam_3] => 
            [amsam_4] => 
            [amsam_12] => fghfg
            [amsam_5] => fghfg
            [amsam_11] => fgf
            [amsam_6] => 
            [amsam_10] => 
            [amsam_9] => 
            [amsam_8] => fghf
            [amsam_7] => 
        )

    [UserProfileContact] => Array
        (
            [email] => jayashree+profile25@jbcs.co.in
            [permanent_address] => fhgfhg
            [permanent_country_id] => 1
            [permanent_zone_id] => 1
            [permanent_city_id] => 1
            [local_address] => 
            [local_country_id] => 1
            [local_zone_id] => 1
            [local_city_id] => 1
            [phone_1] => 2134657898
            [phone_2] => 
            [phone_3] => 
            [phone_4] => 
        )

    [images] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                    [type] => 
                    [tmp_name] => 
                    [error] => 4
                    [size] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                    [type] => 
                    [tmp_name] => 
                    [error] => 4
                    [size] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                    [type] => 
                    [tmp_name] => 
                    [error] => 4
                    [size] => 0
                )

        )

)`
```

It always goes to else part, but when I print the error array it's empty.

Comment: What does it mean "getting failed"? Could you add more information about the "failure"?. You should also post the relevant part of your code in order to allows better understanding the possible error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by change the validation rule

in validation rule i've used 
`'required' => 'create',`

and changed to

`'on' => 'create',`

now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and modify according your requirement.

```
if(!empty($this->data))
{

    $this->User->set( $this->data['User'] );
    $this->Contractor->set( $this->data['Contractor'] );
    if ($this->User->validates() && $this->Contractor->validates())
    {  
        $this->data['User']['passwd'] = $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['new_passwd']);
        $this->data['User']['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $user = $this->data['User'];
        $contractor = $this->data['Contractor'];
        //pr($this->data);die;
        if( $this->User->save( $user ) )
        {
            $newId = $this->User->getLastInsertId();
            $contractor['user_id'] = $newId;
            if($this->Contractor->save($contractor))
            {
                    $this->redirect('/contractors/index') ;                  
            }
        }
    }else{ 
        $this->validateErrors($this->User);
        $this->validateErrors($this->Contractor);
        $this->render();
    }   
}
```

Comment: i've tried by adding `set` option also                                                                   `$this->UserProfileName->set($this->data['UserProfileName']);
$this->UserProfileName->set($this->data['UserProfileContact']);`